# About JPA onetomany joint table

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two entities User and Event. Each user has a list of events he likes. So I set up a OneToMany map as follow:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "login", length = 64)
    protected String login;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_events",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "login")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "event_id")})
    protected List<Event> events;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Event extends BaseEntity{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "event_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long eventId;

    @Column(name = "title", length = 200)
    protected String title;
}
```

Now I have two users, firstly I make one user like an event and the joint table in database updated correctly. Then I make another user like the same event, but this time there is an error says duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_events_event_id_key". I didn't set any constraint on the joint table so I don't where this constraint comes from. Could anyone help me remove this constraint. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraint was probably set by Hibernate itself, when it generated the schema for you. Since you specified the association as OneToMany, only one user is supposed to like a given event. Hibernate makes it guaranteed by setting a unique constraint on the event_id column of the join table.

Your association should be a ManyToMany, and you should not use CascadeType.ALL, since it would delete all the events a user likes when this user is deleted.

Comment: One quick question: what about @ManyToOne? Will there be a constraint on some places?

Comment: ManyToOne is implemented using a foreign key at the many side pointing to PK of the one side. No need for a unique constraint here.